# C#/.NET (Core): Is the type system safe enough to prevent SQL injections?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am working on a project that's using EF Core; in one specific case, I have to update an entity's Identity using a raw SQLite command.

Building an SqlCommand and executing that does not work for some reason, as well as directly passing the parameters to `ExecuteSqlCommand()`, it always throws an exception (I guess that's a bug in the current Sqlite driver).

However, in theory, shouldn't the following code

```
string commandText = $"UPDATE {table} SET Id={idPair.Value} WHERE Id={idPair.Key};";
```

already prevent SQL injections, because here

- `table` is a tablename I got directly from the DbContext's model
- `idPair` is a guaranteed to be a `KeyValuePair<int, int>`

?

I'm mostly asking because I don't know if I should suppress this specific warning, or try to do it in another way (opening a bug report on EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite is on the to-do list anyways).

Comment: Why not using parameter?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom I don't think that parameters can include table names.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?. I am going to guess that it has to do with the fact that you are trying to update your table Id field. You probably want to update a different field

Comment: @FCin No, but the rest of it ;)

Comment: The type system has nothing to do with SQL Injections. It's the queries you write that matter. String concatenation or formatting -> SQL injection. Parameterized queries, no chance. Tables aren't parameters

Comment: @Fcin table names aren't parameters. If you change the table name you have a different query. It's the same as changing the *code* of a C# or Python function instead of the parameter values

Comment: `string commandText = $"UPDATE {table} SET Id={idPair.Value} WHERE Id={idPair.Key};";` doesn't prevent SQL injection, in fact it's a prime example of SQL injection. It's just a string constructed from arbitrary data. `string commandText = "UPDATE MyTable SET Id=@newId WHERE Id=@oldId;"` used with SqlCommand and eg `int` parameters on the other hand is not only safe, it won't even allow the wrong type of parameter values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the type in question cannot be turned into anything harmful in the resulting SQL, yes. Just keep in mind that it's very easy to come to such code a year later without realizing that there's literally no protection against SQL injection and mistakenly add something that *can* be dangerous. Maybe someone decides to change all your keys to strings. The key point is that there is nothing that will help you recognize a potential problem - no compiler errors, no runtime errors, everything will work just as before until someone abuses the hole. That is, while you can rely on the type system that an `int` will never contain arbitrary `string` values, there's nothing guaranteeing that `idPair` will still be `KeyValuePair<int, int>` a year later.

Also, I'd never say it's *absolutely* impossible to do something bad. The trade-off is usually skewed so far towards parametrized queries that there's little reason not to use them.

Answer (score 8):

It's *unlikely* to cause an issue, but in some cases it might not be entirely safe, either. It's using the current culture, which *could* provide some nasty shocks. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Imagine this somewhere entirely different
        var badCulture = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        badCulture.NumberFormat.NegativeSign = "0 OR 1=1 OR Id=";        
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = badCulture;

        // Here's the code that looks innocent
        var idPair = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(-5, 10);
        string table = "Foo";
        string commandText = $"UPDATE {table} SET Id={idPair.Value} WHERE Id={idPair.Key};";

        Console.WriteLine(commandText);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
UPDATE Foo SET Id=10 WHERE Id=0 OR 1=1 OR Id=5;
```

Now `Id` is set to 10 for all rows in `Foo`...

You *could* force the use of the invariant culture... but I'm not sure it's worth it, to be honest.

I would strongly advise using parameters for *all* values. I realize you can't do so for the table name, and there's no good way round that, but for the values you can and IMO *should* use parameters.

Aside from anything else, if you try to do this carefully for all places you know it to be safe, that can give the impression that it's *always* safe, so an unwary developer could follow the same pattern and use it with string values which would *not* be safe.

There are ways to use interpolated string literals with `FormattableString` to create safe parameterized SQL, but most of the code I've seen would need extra tweaking to allow you to *also* use that for the table name.

Comment: There are no really safe ways to use `FormattableString` to create parameterized queries. EF Core tried this, but as soon as you move that query to a separate line, you have SQL Injection again. It's *very* easy to forget that and extract long strings just to clean up your code. They tried this to fix injection bugs for novice developers and ended up causing other problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: "as soon as you move that query to a separate line, you have SQL Injection again" - only if you assign it to a string. If you assign it to `FormattableString` it would be fine. But I agree you need everyone on the team to be *really* aware of this - and ideally prevent passing a string into anything that would do the right thing with `FormattableString`.

Comment: That's what makes this so dangerous, especially since it creates a false sense of security. It's too easy to fall for this, even when you do know about it.  Using parameters eg in EF Core's [FromSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) requires only one extra line per param, *and* allows you to use named parameters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: But if you have an API that doesn't accept `string` at all, that makes it significantly harder to fall for it, and IMO there are readability advantages. There are pros and cons here, and in most cases I'd probably avoid it - I'm just saying it's not a slam-dunk "you absolutely can't use it safely".

Comment: I know this. I spotted the problem the first time I saw how EF Core used FormattableString, a year or more ago. And yet, a couple of weeks ago I extracted a long query string into a separate `var` variable. I hadn't forgotten, the risk was in the back of my mind as I extracted it and yet, I did it. Luckily, I was passing date parameters and got a syntax error immediatelly. That's why I consider this unsafe, in the sense that it's easy to break and generates a false sense of security. Kind of like driving a Tesla and hitting the breaks too late or not at all because you expected it to stop

Comment: This is a nice answer; however, I found Luaans a bit more concise. Don't get me wrong, your answers do say almost exactly the same thing, but your example is a bit...distracting to me. When I look at this answer, I can only think "yeah, sure, someone's gonna run my Android app on a custom .NET Runtime where this is the standard culture's minus sign", sorry.

Comment: @Follpvosten: It's entirely your call which you accept. The bigger point is that you need to be *really* careful with anything which uses ambient configuration (the thread's default culture) - particularly for anything as sensitive as SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by is the type system safe enough. But you are vulnerable to SQL injection here.

What if `idPair.Key`'s value is `'anything' OR 'x'='x'`?
You will updating the Id to `idPair.Value` on every record.

What you should be doing is passing the values in via a parameter see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Example here:

```
context.Blogs
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogsForUser {0}", user)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Their pair is `<int, int>`, there's no way `Key` is `'anything' OR 'x' = 'x'`.

Comment: While it's a very nice syntax, I have to say I'm worried a lot of people would look at this and not realize that it's not equivalent to `string.Format(...)` :/

Comment: @DaisyShipton: interesting, however the possible threat coming from a misconfigured formatter seems rather theoretical. Are you aware of any actual attack attempts that would try this vector?

Comment: @WiktorZychla: No, I've never seen this in reality, but it's a warning against assuming that things will always be formatted the same way

Comment: @WiktorZychla it doesn't have to be an *attack* to cause problems. Syntax errors due to unexpected thousand or date separators will still break the app. How will 100000 be formatted in *India* where they use hundred separators ? Bad data is even worse. Imagine using a DateTime value like September 11 and the server having a *different* locale. If the value is sent as a string you could get September 11 or November 9. Or sending *any* non-US character. You could get garbled text, or you could lose it entirely

Answer (score -1):

The SQL Injection attack typically exposes your code because the values passed into the SQL originate in user input. In your case your code is exposed to SQL Injection, but validation of the incoming parameter values (especially if not generated by user input) would be sufficient to prevent any vulnerability.

Check for any operator symbols and embedded quotes, and reject parameters that have them, or pro-actively escape those symbols before embedding the variables.

Comment: I'd always prefer a whitelisting approach over a blocklisting one. If you're expecting only latin alphabet characters and/or digits, check for that specifically and outright *reject* any other input.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - maybe; but do you think thats what the .net framework SqlParameter does ? It just checks the Type and considers the SQL syntax and escapes obvious values. Theres nothing magic about preventing SQL Injection that the SqlParameter class does - its simple text input validation and handling.

Comment: @PhillipH no it doesn't. That's not what SqlParameter does. These are *real query parameters*, in the same fashion that a function's parameters are parameters, not string replacements. It's not a *.NET* feature, it's a *database* feature. The *databases* allow clients to pass parameters outside the query in the RPC call. Outside .NET these are called "server-bound parameters". The *servers* create an execution plan based on the query, then use the parameter *values* in the *execution plan*.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - point taken, but the OP cant use SqlParameter because he's generating dynamic SQL including the table name. If we look into SqlParameter.ParseAndQuoteIdentifier we can see that the .net library takes the SQL Parameters and escapes their content based on their type. All that SQL Command does is built a StringBuilder and create the literal text you see in SQL Profiler. I agree that SQL Server wont allow dynamic SQL using sp_executesql, but the basic task of input validation and escaping is still done by SqlParameter.

Comment: @PhillipH wrong. For reference, check the actual [TDS RPC Request wire format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd357576.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Notice the `ParameterData` field. I suspect you used libraries or ORMs that *don't* use parameterized queries because their authors don't understand their use and think a script with `sp_executesql` with some encoding is OK. Anything based on FreeTDS for example has that problem. Try passing an emoji from Ruby on Rails running on older Debian versions for example, that didn't support that character range.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I think we're straying too far from the OP here, but I used ILSpy and got the code directly from the System.Data.SqlParameter framework decompile. It literally does AppendString.

Comment: @PhillipH no again. You don't need to decompile anything, the source is available on Github and referencesource. It's not *SqlParameter* that creates the query either, it's SqlCommand. Which, [doesn't inject the parameters in the query](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/sqlclient/SqlCommand.cs,5363). And the protocol *does* pass the parameters separately. No, we aren't straying far. Claiming parameters are just interpolation is a very dangerous idea that makes people use bad coding practices and rely on insecure workarounds

Comment: @PhillipH btw there's *no* call to AppendString in [SqlParameter.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlParameter.cs). SqlParameter is *not* in the `System.Data` namepace since it's specific to SQL Server. It's in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace. The base class of all parameter objects, [DbParameter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/System/Data/Common/DBParameter.cs), doesn't contain anything either. Perhaps you are looking at something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180023/discussion-between-philliph-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Just to comment on the relevance of this - there is no user input involved here. `table` comes directly from EF, and `idPair` is an entry in a Dictionary<int, int> generated by my code, serialized and then deserialized (if a user were to send a custom request to this, it would immediately throw an exception if a key or value in this dictionary cannot be parsed to an int). EDIT: Nevermind, a user cannot in any way possible manipulate this JSON string - it is retrieved from the server-side of the software, so the user would have to reverse-engineer the server-side first.